# MySQL Select grouped query

Tags: mysql

I have the following table that connects 2 tables.

```
id   contact_id   tag_id
1      1             10
2      1             11
3      1             14  
4      2             10
5      2             14
6      2             16 
7      2             18
8      3             10
9      3             16
10     3             18
```

I need a select statement that gives the contact_ids that
have tag_id 10 and 14. So in this example the result would be
contact_id 1 and 2.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `SELECT... FROM... WHERE... IN(...) GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT([DISTINCT] ...) = x;` Where x is the number of arguments in IN()

Comment: Please post your schema, and what query you have tried

Answer (score 0):

To get all of records that match that criteria it goes like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table name or select statement>
WHERE tag_id IN (10,14)
```

Or if you need only contact_id:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contact_id
FROM <table name or select statement>
WHERE tag_id IN (10,14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague about what you need and I don't have enough rep to comment. So this may help. If this isn't what you're looking for you can calrify and I will update this answer

```
SELECT DISTINCT contact_id 
FROM tablename 
WHERE tag_id=10 
OR tag_id=14
```

edit: I was too late with this answer :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT contact_id
FROM <table name or select statement>
WHERE tag_id IN (10,14)
```

That's what i was looking for, i knew it had to be something simple.